# Error while returning boolean from lambda expressions

Tags: c++, lambda, boolean

```
bool markersFormRectangle = [](std::vector<cv::Point2f> markerCoords) {
  cv::Point2f center(
    (markerCoords[0].x + markerCoords[1].x + markerCoords[2].x + markerCoords[3].x) / 4,
    (markerCoords[0].y + markerCoords[1].y + markerCoords[2].y + markerCoords[3].y) / 4
  );

  float dd1 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[0]);
  float dd2 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[1]);
  float dd3 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[2]);
  float dd4 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[3]);

  return (fabs(dd1-dd2) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd3) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd4) < 5);
};
```

I am trying to use the above stated lambda expressions which checks if the four points form a near rectangular shape. But the compiler complains with the error: **called object type 'bool' is not a function or function pointer** when I try to use the lambda expression in an if statement the following way:

```
if (markersFormRectangle(markerPoints)) {
    //do something
}
```

When I change the return type `auto` it doesn't give me that error. I'm pretty new to using lambda functors. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong and why the compiler doesn't give anymore error if the type is changed to `auto`?

Comment: You need to call the function (execute the lambda) by adding `()` after the closing brace `}`

Answer (score 5):

In this declaration

```
        bool markersFormRectangle = [](std::vector<cv::Point2f> markerCoords)
        {
            cv::Point2f center((markerCoords[0].x +markerCoords[1].x + markerCoords[2].x + markerCoords[3].x) / 4,
                    (markerCoords[0].y +markerCoords[1].y + markerCoords[2].y + markerCoords[3].y) / 4);

            float dd1 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[0]);
            float dd2 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[1]);
            float dd3 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[2]);
            float dd4 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[3]);

            return (fabs(dd1-dd2) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd3) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd4) < 5);
        };
```

the initializer is a lambda expression while the declared variable has the type bool. There is no implicit or context-dependent conversion from the type of a lambda expression to the type `bool`.

Take into account that each lambda has its own unique type.

So you have to write

```
        auto markersFormRectangle = [](std::vector<cv::Point2f> markerCoords)
        {
            cv::Point2f center((markerCoords[0].x +markerCoords[1].x + markerCoords[2].x + markerCoords[3].x) / 4,
                    (markerCoords[0].y +markerCoords[1].y + markerCoords[2].y + markerCoords[3].y) / 4);

            float dd1 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[0]);
            float dd2 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[1]);
            float dd3 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[2]);
            float dd4 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[3]);

            return (fabs(dd1-dd2) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd3) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd4) < 5);
        };
```

From the C++14 Standard (5.1.2 Lambda expressions)

> 3 The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the
>   closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type — called the
>   closure type — whose properties are described below. This class type
>   is neither an aggregate (8.5.1) nor a literal type (3.9)....

To specify explicitly the lambda return type you could write using the trailing return type specifier

```
        auto markersFormRectangle = [](std::vector<cv::Point2f> markerCoords) -> bool
        {
            cv::Point2f center((markerCoords[0].x +markerCoords[1].x + markerCoords[2].x + markerCoords[3].x) / 4,
                    (markerCoords[0].y +markerCoords[1].y + markerCoords[2].y + markerCoords[3].y) / 4);

            float dd1 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[0]);
            float dd2 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[1]);
            float dd3 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[2]);
            float dd4 = cv::norm(center - markerCoords[3]);

            return (fabs(dd1-dd2) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd3) < 5) && (fabs(dd1 - dd4) < 5);
        };
```

though it unnecessary.

Bear in mind that (5.1.2 Lambda expressions)

> 7 The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body
>   (8.4) of the function call operator,...

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas can only be stored in a variable of type `auto` or converted to a function pointer (e.g. using `std::function`), if you want to get the result of your lambda you need to call it fist. Your code should be either:

```
auto markers = []{ return true; };
bool value = markers();
```

or

```
bool value = []{ return true; }();
```

depending on whether you are trying to store the lambda or its result.

Comment: Careful there: `auto` is not a type and `std::function` is not a function pointer.

Comment: @Rakete1111 yes `auto` isn't a type but isn't "variable of type auto" a reasonable abbreviation for "variable with automatically deduced type" (especially as the question is about lambdas not the meaning of auto). I never said that `std::function` is a function pointer just that you might use it to convert a lambda to a function pointer.

Comment: 1) don't think so 2) well that's also wrong then. `std::function` just stores the lambda directly.